# Angular Karma Test, not sure how to test XML response and returned XML has a parse error

Tags: xml, unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-services

I have a simple service in my Angular App (written in TypeScript) that loads a static XML file and then returns a formatted XML Document, it looks like this...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { WindowService } from '../window-service/window.service';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private xmlHeaders: any = {
        Accept: 'application/xml',
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    };

    constructor(private windowService: WindowService, private http: Http) {
    }

    getXML(): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get('/assets/data/data.xml', {
            headers: this.xmlHeaders
        }).map((response) => this.parseXML(response.text()));

    }

    parseXML(rawText): any {

        const window = this.windowService.getWindow();

        if (typeof (<any>window).DOMParser !== 'undefined') {

            return (new (<any>window).DOMParser()).parseFromString(rawText, 'text/xml');

        } else if (typeof (<any>window).ActiveXObject !== 'undefined' && new (<any>window).ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')) {

            const xmlDoc = new (<any>window).ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            xmlDoc.async = 'false';
            xmlDoc.loadXML(rawText);
            return xmlDoc;

        } else {
            throw new Error('Yikes! There\'s no XML Parser!!!');
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have written a test file for my service, it looks like so...

```
import { async, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ResponseOptions, BaseRequestOptions, Http, Response, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';
import { assertThat, is, truthy, hasProperties, contains} from 'hamjest';
import { SinonStub, stub} from 'sinon'
import { wasCalled } from '../test/matcher/wasCalled';
import { returnXMLdoc} from '../test/data-functions/mockXML';
import { WindowService } from '../window-service/window.service';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

describe('DataService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                DataService,
                MockBackend,
                BaseRequestOptions,
                WindowService, // ToDo: Mock this,
                {
                    provide: Http,
                    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
                    useFactory: (backendInstance: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
                        return new Http(backendInstance, defaultOptions);
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });

    let sut: DataService;
    let backend: MockBackend;

    beforeEach(inject([
        DataService, MockBackend
    ], (dataService: DataService, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
        sut = dataService;
        backend = mockBackend;
    }));

    it('should create an instance', () => {

        assertThat(sut, is(truthy()));
    });

    describe('getXML()', () => {

        it('should call backend with headers', async(() => {
            const assertionCall: SinonStub = stub();
            backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
                assertThat(connection.request.headers.toJSON().Accept, contains('application/xml')
                );
                assertionCall();
            });
            sut.getXML();

            assertThat(assertionCall, wasCalled());
        }));

        xit('should return XML data', async(() => {

            const assertionCall: SinonStub = stub();
            backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(returnXMLdoc(null)));
            });

            sut.getXML().subscribe((response) => {
                // toTo: put test here...

                // also if I console.log(response) there is a parsing error!
                assertionCall();
            });

            assertThat(assertionCall, wasCalled());
        }));

    });
});
```

The problem is... (and I'm not so great with tests) is that I am unsure how to test what is returned? I have also noticed that inside the second test when I try to output the content the XML has a formatting error.

This is the console log:

## Document

```
<html><body><parsererror xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
</div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror></body></html>
```

You will notice a `returnXMLdoc(null)` function is used for the mock data, this is the content of the `import { returnXMLdoc } from '../test/data-functions/mockXML';`  The data that is returned (the XML doc) is the same as the content of the static file I make a http request to in my service.

```
export function returnXMLdoc(selector) {

    const rawText = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <package>
          <level id="l1">
            <unit id="u1">
              <activity id="a1"></activity>
              <activity id="a2"></activity>
            </unit>
            <unit id="u2">
              <activity id="a3"></activity>
            </unit>
          </level>
          <level id="l2">
            <unit id="u3">
              <activity id="a4"></activity>
            </unit>
          </level>
        </package>`;

    const xmlDoc = (new (<any>window).DOMParser()).parseFromString(rawText, 'text/xml');

    if (selector) {
        return xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(selector);
    }

    return xmlDoc;
}
```

Can someone please give me advice on how to test the getXML service and what it returns. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here

```
connection.mockRespond(new Response(returnXMLdoc(null)));
```

You should pass a [`ResponseOptions`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/ResponseOptions-class.html) to the `Response` constructor. With the `ResponseOptions`, you can set all the values you need

```
const options = new ResponseOptions({
  body: `<raw>XML</raw>`,
  status: 200,
  headers: new Header({
    'content-type': 'application/xml'
  })
})
new Response(options);
```

When you call `response.text()` on the client side, you will just get the raw body `<raw>XML</raw>`